# After upgrading laravel 5.1 to 5.2 \App::environment() always returning "production"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I upgraded laravel 5.1 to 5.2, everything looks good.
But when try to access the app environment not getting what expected.

```
When i dd($_ENV) this is what i get 
"APP_ENV" => "vagrant"
"APP_DEBUG" => "true"
"DB_HOST" => "localhost"  

But When dd(\App::environment());
"production"

P.S. even I checked in tinker: dd(env('APP_ENV')) gives me "vagrant"
but dd(\App::environment()) gives me "production".
Dont you think it is odd :(
```

This is wierd :(

Anyone face this problem ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you missed a step in the upgrade process:

> Configuration
>
> Environment Value
>
> Add an env configuration option to your app.php configuration file that looks like the following:
>
> ```
> 'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
> ```

P.S. You can check the value from the artisan command:

```
php artisan env
```

Comment: @owenconti +1 Thanks a lot that helped me too

Comment: @Cowboy - Can you mark my reply as the answer to the question?

Comment: This did not work for me as expected when using [homestead](https://github.com/laravel/homestead), because there already was an `APP_ENV` variable populated via php-fpm which could *not* be overridden via .env file. I just wrote a more detailed explanation on the how's and why's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34838187/413531). Long story short: Make sure not to set any environment variables **outside** of .env files if you want to change them **via** .env files.

Comment: hey.. check this one my tutorial on how to load multiple environment
http://developers.ph/laravel-framework/laravel-5/how-to-setup-multiple-environment-for-laravel-5-developers-way/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you changed in your .env file it does not take correct values from that, the problem is due to some configuration cache.Try running following commands, hope will work

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```