# How to configure a pre-existed project of PHP with Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, localhost, php-7

I have Ubuntu 16.04; Php7-fpm; Nginx and MySql installed.

I had downloaded a project from Github and take it to `/var/www` and granted permissions with following command (kinbuweb is the project folder containing a "public" folder which has the index.php file):

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/kinbuweb/public`

`sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`

I had copied the  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file as a template to configure mine in *sites-available* and modified it to point to my index.php file:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid         understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of  Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/kinbuweb/public;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name kinbu.localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {

            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

On my local host file I configure the page for local testing (which is my objective)
with `sudo nano /etc/hosts`
and added the new changes with my IP at this moment I have in my host file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       tranquilidad
190.165.34.21   kinbu.localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The problem is that when I go to `http://kinbu.localhost/` I got an HTTP ERROR 500 and a page kinbu.localhost is not working message.

This project is a dynamic one (I guess) I had proved with a simple info.php file and worked, test some answers in other questions but they are outdated. I don't know what is happening here, I'm a little bit new, any opinions o suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the nginx error log say?

Comment: Hello @vishnuj I got no errors in syntax. I check it with `nginx -t ` command. How can I check the error log? Thanks for answering Vishnuj

Comment: tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: The issue seems to be with  your PHP script rather than the nginx configuration.

Comment: @vishnuj I got this http://pastebin.com/hVkr4RuV how can I solutionate?

Comment: Are you using composer?

Comment: @Vishnuj Yes, I installed composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the error is in PHP.
`/var/www/kinbuweb/bootstrap/autoload.php` seems to be missing.  Something seems to be off about your bootstrap installation.

Did you do a composer install where you have the composer.json?

--EDIT--

Try this:

```
cd /var/www/kinbuweb
/home/luis/composer.phar/composer update --no-scripts
/home/luis/composer.phar install
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Vishnuj I have a /home/luis/composer.phar file, but where I can find the composer.json file is located?

Comment: In your project root folder.  How did you install bootstrap?

Comment: Boostrap was already in the project. These are the files in the boostrap folder of the project (/var/www/kinbuweb/bootstrap): autoload.php -->http://pastebin.com/mpk6iDv8 paths.php-->http://pastebin.com/cMf3uQZ5  and start.php -->http://pastebin.com/3etg7mGX

Comment: Can you check if there is a composer.json file in /var/www/kinbuweb

Comment: Yes, I located the composer.json file in /var/www/kinbuweb it have inside: http://pastebin.com/7bVuvH79

Comment: I run the last commads the first one ran good, but in the second (which I has to use sudo for permissions) prompt that php artisan was clear-compiled and Mycript PHP extension was required. And this error `Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1`

Comment: `home/luis/composer.phar dump-autoload -o`  Try running this followed by a composer update.

Comment: When I run `/home/luis/composer.phar dump-autoload -o` I got `Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/luis
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section`do you think I should move the file to /var/www/kinbuweb ?

Comment: Either you can move composer.phar or first cd into /var/www/kinbuweb and then try this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I moved the file to /var/www/kinbuweb and restart Nginx. Now the page says "Mcrypt PHP extension required."

Comment: Install the extenstion: `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`

Comment: Thanks for help. I did everything except php5enmod mycryp because I'm on Php7.0. Even though now I have this error: http://imgur.com/a/pZkIo thanks for all the help.

Comment: Add permissions to the storage folder. `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/kinbuweb/app/storage`  Please do not use 777 in production environments.  PS: An upvote would be nice.

Comment: I added the permissions and now I have this: http://imgur.com/cTgB3rC think I will repeat all the process again. I can't upvote because I'm new in the forum...

Comment: Set the environment variables.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346299/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-env-variables-in-laravel-5

Comment: Ohhhh man @vishnuj thanks!, I changed in `/var/www/kinbuweb/bootstrap/start.php` file                                `$env = $app->detectEnvironment([   'development' =>['jedabero-lmint', 'Inspiron-N4050', 'MANHATTAN-PC'], 'local' =>['local'], ]);`  the  `'local'`into `'tranquilidad'` which is my hostname, getting it with `hostname`command in terminal. But now when I go to a subdirectory (example: login) look what happens. http://imgur.com/PN6u2jR

Comment: Hey man, I resolved the error 404 when I switched pages: changing line in my server config `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` into `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`